Why and how does から work with「話を聞く」?
I came across the following sentence in my Japanese textbook:

リサイクルの店を開くにあたって、いろいろな方面から話を聞いた。

Which I translate as "at the occasion of opening a recycling shop, [ I ] consulted with / asked for the opinion / discussed it with several parties.
Now, I would have expected the particle to be に instead of から, because the direction of the communication is the subject [ I ] asking to いろいろな方面, and not [ I ] being asked by いろいろな方面, because it's the subject [ I ] who plans to open a new shop and not the other way around:

リサイクルの店を開くにあたって、いろいろな方面に話を聞いた。

So, why is it から instead of に? would に also work here?
Related questions:

話を聞く connected?
リサイクルの店を開くにあたって、色々な方面から話を聞いた。 とはどういう意味ですか?


I think it's as simple as this being the 'listen' or 'hear' meaning rather than 'ask'.

It's doesn't matter if 聞く should mean "to hear" or "to ask" here, and in your sentence without further context, both explanations are likely. However, that's not your question, and your question is about the usage of から.
To answer directly, the usage of から is perfectly natural, and in this case, it can actually be translated literally to "from" in English.

色々な方面から話を聞いた I asked for(or listened to) stories from all sorts of perspectives.

方面 is "perspective", so just like how we say in English "from a perspective," in Japanese it's also "方面から"
に works if 聞く is interpreted as "to ask", but still, that's very unnatural. When に is used with 聞く, it's often the subject that's being asked, aka 僕に話を聞く "Ask me for stories", and not from which perspective your question is asked. With 方面 "perspective", から "from" is simply the more natural choice, even in English.
P.S. Your confusion may have risen from the other meaning of 方面 "direction". Aka you might see a road sign on the highway saying 東京方面 "direction to Tokyo". For this meaning of 方面, you'd use に.
